# C# implementation of CW-SSIM similarity index

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

The question is quite simple: does anyone know of a C# implementation of the CW-SSIM (Complex Wavelet Structural Similarity) index? I have searched online, but could only find the 'regular' SSIM.